# How can I open a form result in a new window?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form within an iframe on my web page. When the submit button is clicked, the result is viewed in the window that contained my web page.
How do I open the result in new window instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you adjust the form html itself? `<form target="_blank">`

Comment: Is it possible to view the result in the same page but in whole page instead of iframe ?

Answer (score 3):

Try providing an `onclick` function like this:

```
<input type='submit' onclick="this.form.target='_blank'; return true;">
```