# Opening form result in new window

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search

I have form with two buttons submit.

The code is:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="q" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="site" value="site search" class="submit" />&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" name="google" value="google search" class="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What I want is that if you press the button, Google results will open in a new window. I think it should be done with JavaScript.

Comment: Not javascript, just set target="_blank" on the form tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open a form result in a new window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866782/how-can-i-open-a-form-result-in-a-new-window)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get" target="_blank">
```

Comment: I think he needs different behaviour for the two submit buttons. The first is just a submit, the latter ask google given the query field is the same for the two actions

Comment: @Eineki so make 2 diff forms using the same input

Answer (score 0):

In index.php you could perform separate functions depending on what button was pressed.  For example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET('google'))&&isset($_GET('q'))){
     header('Location: http://www.google.ca/search?q=' . $_GET('q'));
}
if(isset($_GET('site'))&&isset($_GET('q'))){
     //function here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed achieve that through javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenGoogleSearch() {
        var q = document.getElementById("google").value;
        window.open("http://google.com/search?q=" + q);
    }
</script>
```

This does require the form to be altered slightly:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <input id="google" type="text" name="q" size="20" /></td>
    <input type="submit" name="site" value="site search" class="submit" />&nbsp;
    <input type="button" name="google" value="google search" class="submit" onclick="OpenGoogleSearch()" />
</form>
```

The javascript uses the id of the text field (which you should add) to get the entered value. Instead of a submit, the google search uses a normal button with an onclick attribute, which calls the javascript function.

Note that this only opens the google search in a new window; if you want to open the 'site search' in a new window as well, you should add `target="_blank"`, as Neal said.